# Optimizing XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

#### Background

We have a project that was started in .NET 1.1, moved to .NET 2.0, and recently moved again to .NET 3.5. The project is extremely data-driven and utilizes XML for many of its data files. Some of these XML files are quite large and I would like to take the opportunity I currently have to improve the application's interaction with them. If possible, I want to avoid having to hold them entirely in memory at all times, but on the other hand, I want to make accessing their data fast.

The current setup uses [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) and [`XPathDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) (depending on when it was written and by whom). The data is looked up when first requested and cached in an internal data structure (rather than as XML, which would take up more memory in most scenarios). In the past, this was a nice model as it had fast access times and low memory footprint (or at least, satisfactory memory footprint). Now, however, there is a feature that queries a large proportion of the information in one go, rather than the nicely spread out requests we previously had. This causes the XML loading, validation, and parsing to be a visible bottleneck in performance.

#### Question

Given a large XML file, what is the most efficient and responsive way to query its contents (such as, "does element A with id=B exist?") repeatedly without having the XML in memory?

Note that the data itself can be in memory, just not in its more bloated XML form if we can help it. In the worst case, we could accept a single file being loaded into memory to be parsed and then unloaded again to free resources, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Considering that we're already caching data where we can, this question could also be read as "which is faster and uses less memory; [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0), [`XPathDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0), parsing based on [`XmlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0), or [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)/[LINQ-to-XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb387098(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?"

*Edit:* Even simpler, can we randomly access the XML on disk without reading in the entire file at once?

#### Example

An XML file has some records:

```
<MyXml>
  <Record id='1'/>
  <Record id='2'/>
  <Record id='3'/>
</MyXml>
```

Our user interface wants to know if a record exists with an id of 3. We want to find out without having to parse and load every record in the file, if we can. So, if it is in our cache, there's no XML interaction, if it isn't, we can just load that record into the cache and respond to the request.

#### Goal

To have a scalable, fast way of querying and caching XML data files so that our user interface is responsive without resorting to multiple threads or the long-term retention of entire XML files in memory.

I realize that there may well be a blog or MSDN article on this somewhere and I will be continuing to Google after I've posted this question, but if anyone has some data that might help, or some examples of when one approach is better or faster than another, that would be great.

---

**Update**
[The XMLTeam published a blog today](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119095609/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/14/effective-xml-part-1-choose-the-right-api.aspx) that gives great advice on when to use the various XML APIs in .NET. It looks like something based on `XmlReader` and `IEnumerable` would be my best option for the scenario I gave here.

Comment: How big is this xml file?  Event if it is several MBs a single copy of it wouldn't take up that much memory in the big scope of things.

Comment: We have many and they are large. However, you're focusing perhaps on the wrong portion. Loading that file into memory takes time, we'd rather only read the parts we need when we need them, rather than the entire file. The file system is the biggest bottleneck I can see in this.

Comment: If you are already cacheing, could you use XML reader to scan the file (search for records where id = "A"), and then load the results into your in-memory data objects?  the XML reader is non-cached, but you would only need it once per search.

2nd question:  If you are looking at a rewrite anyway, have you considered switching to a local database engine instead of using XML?  Something like SQL Server Express, or Compact edition? (both are free)

Comment: @JMarsch: I like your thinking. Unfortunately, we can't move to something else for the files as they come from a separate process that isn't up for rework. As for XmlReader, my current approach that I want to pursue is just that, use a reader to cache the data in-memory - I was just making sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XML I only know of two ways

XMLReader -> stream the large XML data in
or use the XML DOM object model and read the entire XML in at once into memory.

If the XML is big, we have XML files in 80 MB range and up, reading the XML into memory is a performance hit.    There is no real way to "merge" the two ways of dealing with XML documents.  Sorry.

Comment: If you're using 80MB of XML, it may be time to consider using a database as your primary store and relegating XML exclusively to data transfer.  This has the added benefit of letting you "query" using "structured query language".

Comment: We actually are in fact doing that.  The XML is the result of a query.  Due to it's size we are always concerned with speed and overhead to consume that query.

Comment: I am using XmlReader to read the XML into XDocument and then Linq-to-XML to query the contents. By moving the loading into a streaming extension method, I can load multiple large documents sequentially and leverage LINQ (making sure not to repeat the load multiple times). So far, it's working quite well (29 MB of files in under 30 seconds). I skip XSD validation as we can safely assume at this point that the files are valid, which obviously gives us a speed enhancement.

Comment: In addition, we're not using a DB because we don't yet know what structure that DB should take, nor do we have the luxury of time to get the data into the DB before querying it - hence the LINQ-to-XML approach.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this white paper a while ago when I was trying to stream XML: [API-based XML streaming with FLWOR power and functional updates](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.7182&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  The paper tries to work with in memory XML but leverage LINQ accessing.

Maybe someone will find it interesting.

Comment: I tried this also, there are also some people who have published working classes that fit the API described in the paper.  More or less they sort of seek() to a location in the underlying stream and instanciate XLinq objects from there for ease of use.  It's unfortunate that an input XStreamingElement analouge is not available.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound stupid.
But, if you have simple things to query, you can use regex over xml files. (the way they do grep in unix/linux).

I apologize if it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question sounds like a schema validation would work best.  If you have access to the XSD's or can create them you could use an algorithm similar to this:

```
    public void ValidateXmlToXsd(string xsdFilePath, string xmlFilePath)
    {
        XmlSchema schema = ValidateXsd(xsdFilePath);
        XmlDocument xmlData = new XmlDocument();
        XmlReaderSettings validationSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();

        validationSettings.Schemas.Add(schema);
        validationSettings.Schemas.Compile();
        validationSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        validationSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        validationSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);
        XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, validationSettings);

        xmlData.Load(xmlFile);
        xmlFile.Close();
    }

    private XmlSchema ValidateXsd(string xsdFilePath)
    {
        StreamReader schemaFile = new StreamReader(xsdFilePath);
        XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaFile, new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler));
        schema.Compile(new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler));
        schemaFile.Close();
        schemaFile.Dispose();

        return schema;
    }

    private void ValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new XmlSchemaException(e.Message);
    }
```

If the xml fails to validate the `XmlSchemaException` is thrown.

As for LINQ, I personally prefer to use `XDocument` whenever I can over `XmlDocument`.  Your goal is somewhat subjective and without seeing exactly what you're doing I can't say go this way or go that way with any certainty that it would help you.  You can use XPath with `XDocument`.  I would have to say that you should use whichever suits your needs best.  There's no issue with using XPath sometimes and LINQ other times.  It really depends on your comfort level along with scalability and readability.  What will benefit the team, so to speak.

Comment: We already use XSD validation - our main bottleneck is disk access and I would like to find a way, I guess, of randomly accessing the XML so as not to load the entire file before we use it. I suspect it won't be possible without some major rework.

Answer (score 0):

An XmlReader will use less memory than an XmlDocument because it doesn't need to load the entire XML into memory at one time.

Comment: Yup, it is as it is non-cached. However, this may not be the fastest way to do it - I think a compromise is needed, if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought on the comments of JMarsch. Even if the XML generation your process is not up for discussion, have you considered a DB (or a subset of XML files acting as indexes) as an intermediary? This would obviously only be of benefit if the XML files aren't updated more that once or twice a day. I guess this would need to be weighed up against your existing caching mechanism.

I can't speak to speed, butt I prefer XDocument/LINQ because of the syntax.

Rich